# Symbol =< in Batch Script

Tags: shell, batch-file

I came across a batch script with line `set /p TestVersion=<version.txt`

My interpretation of this command line is :-
/p signifies pause the script till the version.txt is read and feed its value to TestVersion ?

Is =< symbol used when an input is fed to other variable ?

Pls clarify the symbol details.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

That code takes the first line of version.txt and stores it in the variable TestVersion.

`set /p` is a command for taking in user input, and `<` is an input redirection symbol. When data is piped into a `set` command, it is read in one line at a time per instance of input redirection, so you can run that line over and over and it will always give the same result, but if you say something like

```
(
    set /p first_line=
    set /p second_line=
)<version.txt
```

then first_line will contain the first line in the file and second_line will contain the second line in the file.